# Place and scale image using augmented reality in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, augmented-reality

I am working on android app which do following things

1. Opens the camera and place the user selected images over camera view
2. on image user will play like moving image and zooming to find position
3. App as to calculate the zooming position to real world as user zoom the image, as did in this app [Augment](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ar.augment)!

some how i managed to achieve 1 and 2 things, but for third one i dont know how to calculate real world scaling to fit the object as user zoom is not happening.I appreciate your help to achieve this.

please respond to me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: can anyone please respond....

Comment: have u found any solution?